# Manufacturer pairs 6 ft tall vinyl fence with 8 ft posts - should I find 9 ft posts?

Tags: fence, post, vinyl, backyard

My research has shown that fence posts should be dug to a depth of at least 1/3 of the height of the post—for a six foot fence, the post depth would be 3 feet.

I purchased a [6 foot vinyl privacy fence](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Freedom-Actual-5-66-ft-x-5-45-ft-Pre-Assembled-Brighton-White-Vinyl-Panel/3160109) from Lowe's, and the manufacturer's recommended post was a [5"x5"x8' post](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Freedom-Common-5-in-x-5-in-x-8-ft-Actual-5-in-x-5-in-x-8-ft-Pre-Assembled-White-Vinyl-Fence-Blank-Post/4009495), an entire foot short of what I would have expected. Indeed, Lowe's doesn't even appear to sell a 9 foot fence post (without routed holes). Should I return the 8 foot posts and find something longer? Or is there some way to approximate a longer post (e.g. concrete+rebar going deeper or something?)?

- My soil is extremely rocky (on a mountain in Utah County), but otherwise loamy.
- It's not usually windy, 40 mph sustained winds with 60 mph gusts would be the strongest wind you might see in a year. Most of the length of the fence will separate my house and the neighbors, about 20 feet away from either house, which I'm hoping should should act as a windbreak.
- The frost line here is 36 inches
- I'm planning on using concrete to set the posts.

Comment: 1/3 of 6 is 2 1/3 of 8 is 2.666 actual panel height is 5.6.  8 footers will be fine.  Or use 10 foot posts and cut off excess after panel is placed

Comment: For a 6' tall fence, 2' buried is one 3rd of the height above ground, resulting in an 8' post. But this is the *minimum* recommended post length.

Comment: Wind is one concern but frozen ground is a more serious concern. You want the post below the freeze depth.

Comment: With a frost line that deep if use the 10 foot post and cut to fit panel height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm about to put some of these in myself. I believe the [manufacturer's instructions](http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/040933139507_install.pdf) answer this question in Step 2c, shown below. Note that the post does not extend the entire depth of the hole, but the hole is back-filled with concrete to a 30-inch depth before placing the post. That way, the concrete holding the post extends past the frost line, even though the post itself does not.

[image: Post hole design]